# Codeigniter 2.0 third_party folder

Tags: codeigniter

What is this the third_party folder in codeigniter 2.0 and how to use that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Packages** are new to CI2.0 that allow for the `easy distribution of complete sets of resources in a single directory`, containing models, libraries, helpers etc...but not to be confused with modules, as [Phil Sturgeon](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/04/codeigniter-packages-modules) points out quite helpfully.

`$this->load->add_package_path()`

See the [docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) for more

Comment: Link is now dead.  Pretty sure the same content at the link below, http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Answer (score 7):

If your "third party library code" requires a single file to be "loaded" in order for you to make full use of the library then it should go in your **libraries** directory. If your "third party library code" is a folder full of files, many of which may be "loaded" and made use of, then it should go in your **third_party** directory.

That's my interpretation of the CodeIgniter docs for the Loader Class found here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html

Is my interpretation incorrect? If so LMK!

Answer (score 1):

The current convention is to use a folder called "vendor".  "third_party" is not commonly used anymore.

Comment: And is there a place where this convention is outlined?

Comment: Actually the [google closure library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) is using a `third_party` folder

Answer (score 0):

As [John explained in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15992103/6225838), a **single-file library** can be loaded by placing it in the *libraries* folder:

```
$this->load->library('my_app');
```

Multiple **single-file libraries** can be loaded similarly with an array:

```
$this->load->library(['email', 'table']);
```

However, if you have a **folder full of classes to be loaded not related to CodeIgniter**, you can still place them in the *third_party* folder, but **do not use `$this->load->add_package_path()`** (it expects a CI structure inside the new *third_party* package, i.e. with models, configs, helpers, etc.).

I leave an example, [Stripe API](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases) has a *lib* folder and an *init.php*, so I did the following:

1. updated *init.php* references from `dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/` to `dirname(__FILE__) . '/`) and placed the file in the *third_party/stripe* folder together with all contents of the *lib* folder;
2. Create, for example, a **libraries/Stripe.php**;
3. This would be its constructor:

   ```
   public function __construct()
   {
     $this->CI =& get_instance();
     require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/stripe/init.php');
     \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($this->CI->config->item('stripe_key_secret'));
     if(ENVIRONMENT === 'development'){
       \Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);
     }
   }
   ```
4. Add to it functions that invoke directly Stripe classes, simple e.g.:

   ```
   public static function create_customer($email, $token) {
     $stripe_result = FALSE;
     try {
       $stripe_result = \Stripe\Customer::create([
         'email' => $email,
         'description' => "Customer for $email",
         'source' => $token // obtained with Stripe.js
       ]);
     } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
       return 'Error ' . $e->getHttpStatus() . ': '.
         $e->stripeCode .  ' -> '.
         var_export($e->getJsonBody()['error'], TRUE);
     } catch (Exception $e) {
       return 'Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe -> '.
         var_export($e, TRUE);
     }
     return $stripe_result;
   ```
5. load the library on one of your controllers and invoke the method:

   ```
   $this->load->library('stripe');
   Stripe::create_customer($someones_email, $someones_token); // you can use the result
   ```

Just also leaving the updated URL: [CodeIgniter's Loader Class documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html).