# CodeIgniter third_party

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, architecture, hmvc

This was posted 8 months ago: [Codeigniter 2.0 third_party folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248158/codeigniter-2-0-third-party-folder). This was posted almost a year ago: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/04/codeigniter-packages-modules.

I'm wondering if anything significant has changed since those posts. Particularly, is it possible to share resources between application packages? If not, what are my options? HMVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in the way HMVC is described, but it is possible with CI to share ressources.

Take a look at the bottom of this [documentation page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) - the part labeled **Application "Packages"**.

The documentation describes the use of the third_party folder in your application, but instead you could point the `add_package_path()` method argument to any folder you'd wish.

But, it has it's limitations (which can be seen on the same page).