# How to load javascript css files in codeigniter ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

i wanna migrate my website into CI.
i just simply modified from ci sample file welcome.php
in index() function , i load the view to show.
however , i put many javascripts and css files in the header file . 
and call it by `$this->load->view('header');`
but i can not load the javascript files correctly!
Can anyone give me some tips ? it;s hard to configure how to set the correct path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/order.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/javascripts/order.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/javascripts/order.js"></script>
```

my controller code  as following

```
    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');     
    $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url');

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');


}
```

}

belows are my folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

put your assets folder with `applications, system, assets`

not in application and simple load the `url` helper class in controller where you call the header view part something like

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('header');
```

and simply use something like this in your header file..
because `$this->base_url()` return the `/` folder..

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->base_url();?>assets/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
```

Changing the folder structure because access within the application folder is just for the core part that i know..

here is the link if you want to know more about [URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/nightly_user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: thank you or your support. btw the way if i wanna use some library like phpMailler or zend framwork . sholud i put those folder in applicaions, system level , reight ?

Comment: @poc being true, i don't have much experience about codeigniter, so i think these libraries you have to put in third_party folder.

Comment: @poc yes you can put on the `third_party` folder and to know more about the third party folder, follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248158/codeigniter-2-0-third-party-folder

Comment: Make sure you have added the 'url' into your array in autoload.php under config folder
here ->
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Comment: Using "something like" $this->base_url() led me to an error of not finding the method and fatal exception, realizing afterward that we don't need $this and directly call echo base_url(). works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way with minimal code

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/javascript/jquery.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jogesh_p's answer will surely solve the assets loading problem you have. I would like to follow up on this question you gave

> Thank you or your support. btw the way if i wanna use some library
>   like phpMailler or zend framwork .

You can put in application/libraries/

Then load it in the controller using the Library's Class' Name

```
$this->load->library('phpmailer');
```

Its your choice to load in on the constructor or on the individual method.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I created helper functions to load assets. And here is my code deployed in my application.
*PS: First I planned a good/flexible directory structure*

[**some_helper.php**]

```
/*
 * Created: 2017/12/14 00:28:30
 * Updated: 2017/12/14 00:28:39
 * @params
 * $url_structure = 'assets/js/%s.js'
 * $files = ['main.min', 'social']
 * $echo = FALSE
 *
 */

function load_js($files = [], $url_structure = NULL, $version = '1.0', $echo = FALSE){
    $html = "";
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if($url_structure){
            $file = sprintf($url_structure, $file);
        }
        $file_url = base_url($file);
        $html .= "<script src=\"{$file_url}?v={$version}\"></script>";
    }
    if($echo) {
        echo $html;
    }
    return $html;
}

/*
 * Created: 2017/12/14 00:28:48
 * Updated: 2017/12/14 00:28:51
 * @params
 * $version = '1.0' // Later load from configuration
 * $url_structure = 'assets/js/%s.css'
 * $files = ['main.min', 'social']
 * $echo = FALSE
 *
 */

function load_css($files = [], $url_structure = NULL, $version = '1.0', $echo = FALSE){
    $html = "";
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if($url_structure){
            $file = sprintf($url_structure, $file);
        }
        $file_url = base_url($file);
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"{$file_url}?v={$version}\">";
    }
    if($echo) {
        echo $html;
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Then called in the view

[**some_view.php**]

```
$css = [
    'path' => 'assets/css/%s.css',
    'files' => ['bootstrap.min','style']
];
load_css($css['files'], $css['path'], '1.0', TRUE);
```

Hope it helps someone.
In the case of OP `$css['path'] = 'application/assets/css/%s.css';` will do the trick.

Updated the code on [Github](https://github.com/DrVishalKumarSahu/Codeigniter-Utilities-and-Tricks) which I will keep updating.

Answer (score -2):

assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"

```
    <!-- Include JS -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please also add some explanation?

Comment: Besides the question is already solved with "base_url()", no need to duplicate that answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
function addcategory()
{
    //alert("<?php echo base_url();?>")
     $.ajax({
                complete: function() {}, //Hide spinner
                url : '<?php echo base_url();?>category/search',
                data:$('#add_category').serialize(),
                type : "POST",
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    if(data.code == "200")
                    {
                        alert("category added successfully");
                    }

                        },
                beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest){}, //$.blockUI();
                        cache: false,
                        error : function(data) {
                            }
            });

}
```

Comment: function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
  $('#photo').attr('src', e.target.result);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
 }
  $("#category_photo").change(function(){
  readURL(this);
  });

Comment: class Globel_model extends  CI_Model  {

 function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

function add_record($tablename,$data)
{
 $this->db->insert($tablename, $data); 
 return;
}
}

Comment: You can edit your answer, so that it includes all the code. And please give some additional information about your solution - a wall of code is hard to grasp.